# How to use IronAHK Rusty library directly from C#

Tags: c#, autohotkey, internal

It's a long time already as I wondering about how to mix autohotkey and C#.
At the current moment I want to set global key hook. Something like this:

```
SetGlobalHook("F9", MyDelegate);
```

It looks that Rusty library doesn't supposed to be used directly in such a way. So, I'm afraid to simply change all internal to public and recompile it.

Please don't suggest solutions other then through IronAHK, I know about them.